# Cant find mediaplayer.js

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, silverlight

I am trying to deploy a silverlight webpart solution to my sharepoint foundation site to play videos from assets library and its based on mediaplayer.js but in layouts folder i cant seem to find that js file.

do help!
thanks

Comment: By the way this is the webpart which I am deploying

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint/Use-the-Silverlight-Media-ce36b975

Answer (score 0):

The file should be in:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

If not, you may just need to reinstall. Else wise I am sure you can get a copy from another source.

Comment: do you know anysource from where I can get it?

Comment: Send me an email off my profile.